# Select que pega options de banco mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Então, eu tenho esse código aqui e não to entendendo porque ele não está funcionando.

Sou iniciante em PHP e não to conseguindo fazer ele funcionar.

```
// a conexão com o banco está em outro aquivo, por isso não achei necessário inclui-la aqui

<select id="txt-model" class="field-50" name="estados">
    <option>Selecione um estado</option>
    <?
        $sql = "SELECT FROM estados";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($option = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $estado = $option["nome"];
            $id     = $option["cod_estados"];
            echo "<option id=".$id.">".$estado."</option>";
        };
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Acho que funções `mysql_*` já não existem mais, na última versão do PHP (corrijam-me se estiver errado)

Comment: ta faltando o * no Select-> SELECT FROM estados não vai funcionar. Coloque SELECT * FROM estados ou SELECT cod_estados, nome FROM estados

Comment: Não seria `SELECT * FROM estados` ?

Comment: Pow, eu tenetei colocar o *, que tinha esquecido msm, e não foi, e tentei o  SELECT cod_estados, nome FROM estados e tb não foi, alguem mais?? :)

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM estados";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['nome'];
    echo $row['cod_estados'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);